# Can't open Panel settings with super-alt right-click in gnome-classic after resize

Tags: gnome-panel, gnome-classic

In 12.04, I just tried the pane-setting 'resize' (or autoshrink or what it is named). Now, I don't like it any longer and I would like to switch back. But since the panel is shrunken, there is no longer a place where I can click (with <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>rightclick</kbd>), I'm always in one or another application which lies in the panel.

So, is there another way than clicking on an empty space in the panel to open the settings?

Answer (score 2):

One possible alternative is to enable (tick) the expand property for the panel:

[image]

To do this, install `dconf-tools` either from Software Center or via

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

Then run `dconf-editor` and navigate to `org.gnome.gnome-panel.layout.toplevels`

Comment: No such thing as org.gnome.gnome-panel in Gnome 3.10 @ Ubuntu 14.04 :(